# asp.net mvc - can't design child class inside li tag

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html

This is my Home view:

```
@model IEnumerable<GigHub.Models.Gig>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<ul class="gigs">
    @foreach(var gig in Model)
    {
        <li>  

            <div class="date">
                <div class="month">
                    @gig.DateTime.ToString("MMM")
                </div>
                <div class="day">
                    @gig.DateTime.ToString("d ")
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="details">
                <span class="artist">
                    @gig.Artist.UserName
                </span>
                <span class="genre">
                    @gig.Genre.Name
                </span>
            </div>

        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

I'M trying to set all the text color in "li" tag on red, and set font-size of text in "details" class on 25px, by adding this to site.css file:

```
.gigs > li{
        color: #ff4342;
}

.gigs > li.details {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

the color changes, but not the font-size.

also other designs in  " .gigs > li.details {...} " dont work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
.gigs > li .details {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

`li.details` would mean an `li` with a class of `details`.

`li .details` means any child of `li` with a class of `details`.